# Esconder informação de um collapse ionic/angular

Tags: html, ionic, angular

Tenho um collapse que funciona bem, porém eu preciso de esconder/mostrar o gatilho conforme o index daquele produto.

O que eu tenho atualmente:
Html:

```
<p data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#{{pergunta.id_pergunta}}" (click)="hideInformacoes()" [hidden]="tocouInfo" class="maisInformacoes">Ver mais informações</p>

<div id="{{pergunta.id_pergunta}}" class="alinha collapse">
    Informações do produto
</div>
```

Ts:

```
  hideInformacoes(){
    if(this.tocouInfo == false){
      this.tocouInfo = true;
    }
    else if(this.tocouInfo == true){
      this.tocouInfo = false;
    }
  }
```

Porém como eu estou iterando sobre um ngfor, assim que eu clico no Ver mais informações ele desaparece como esperado, porém ele também esconde o de outros produtos que ainda não foram clicados, preciso descobrir uma forma de passar o index desse produto clicado e esconder apenas ele.
Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após uma procura eu consegui facilmente através do seguinte código:

```
(click)="hideinfo[i] = !hideinfo[i]" [hidden]="hideinfo[i]"
```

Declarei um array hideinfo no meu ts:

```
hideinfo[];
```

Peguei meu index do ng for acrescentando:

```
let i = index;
```